# "error: 'avcodec_open' was not declared in this scope" on attempting to compile untrunc

Tags: c++, video

I have a video recorded by a camera that had a power interruption. As a result, the MP4 file with H.264 codec it was making is damaged. I want to repair this file in Ubuntu 14.04.1. One approach I have seen [suggested](https://superuser.com/a/596402) is to use [untrunc](https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc). I am attempting to compile this but have run into an error I do not know how to address. What I have done so far is as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev libavutil-dev
git clone https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc.git
cd untrunc/
g++ -o untrunc file.cpp main.cpp track.cpp atom.cpp mp4.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil
```

On attempting to compile, I am presented with the following error:

```
track.cpp: In member function 'void Track::parse(Atom*, Atom*)':
track.cpp:217:47: error: 'avcodec_open' was not declared in this scope
     if(avcodec_open(codec.context, codec.codec)<0)
```

Could you suggest a way to address this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`avcodec_open` was deprecated for `avcodec_open2`.  See for instance [this](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-cvslog/2011-November/043754.html) note.  Reading through the docs for `avcodec_open`, it appears that the way to do the replacement is to convert:

```
avcodec_open(a,b);
```

to

```
avcodec_open2(a,b,NULL);
```

This fix is similar to one that was suggested, but not verified in the untrunc library itself, [here](https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc/issues/6).

I tried to verify that the fix worked.  In practice, it was a single line modification in track.cpp.  Take:

```
 if(avcodec_open(codec.context, codec.codec)<0)
```

and replace it with

```
 if(avcodec_open2(codec.context, codec.codec, NULL)<0)
```

(on commit 3c708a, this change is on line 218).  NOTE: I only verified that the code compiled, not that it actually worked the way it was supposed to (I don't have a broken m4v to test on).  Let me know if it works, or if you encounter any other problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. That compiles successfully. (Now all I have to do it get it to work!)

Comment: Read "to convert [...] to `avcodec_open2(a,b,NULL)`". I tried to edit the post, but it was rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Not the exact solution for your question (compile error), but possibly the solution for you primary problem (broken mp4): http://untrunc.it/